# PHP autoloaders and namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces, spl-autoloader

I'm slightly confused by autoloaders and namespaces in PHP.

My classes are organised within an assets file,

```
-- Assets
    -- user
       -- User.php
    -- database
       -- Database.php
```

This is just a simple version, there are more files in each folder (i.e. user, database).

There is no need to worry about conflicting vendor names as there is only one vendor in this project (i.e. me) but for example, using the PSR0 autoloader:

```
function autoload($className)
{
    $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
    $fileName  = '';
    $namespace = '';
    if ($lastNsPos = strripos($className, '\\')) {
        $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
        $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
        $fileName  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';

    require $fileName;
}
```

Do I need to declare a namespace in each of my class files and initilize a class by using `new user\User();`. Is it not possible to initilize it by using `new user_User;`

Many thanks

Comment: `spl_autoload_extensions('.php');` and `spl_autoload_register();` are so good!

Comment: `spl_autoload_register('autoload');` is used to set the autoloader

Comment: Yep, I know. I prefer the built-in autoloader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PSR-0 autoloader convention doesn't *require* you to use namespaces that map to your directory structure. You can also use underscores in the class name for basically the same purpose.

Like the `\` namespace separator, any underscores *in the class name* are converted to `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` when looking up the file to load. So, a class `user_User` and `\user\User` would both result in the autoloader looking for the same file: `user/User.php`.

Comment: Ok, some I'm declaring `$User = new user_User;` but for some reason it's returning this error: `Class 'user_User' not found`

Comment: Are you actually registering this autoloading function (with `spl_autoload_register`)?

Comment: Yes `spl_autoload_register('autoload');`

Comment: If the autoloading function was working, but just returning wrong paths, you'd expect to get an error about the `require` failing. Since you're not, is it possible that the file `Assets/user/User.php` doesn't define a class named `user_User`?

Comment: Damn it! Yes, I named the class `User` instead of `user_User`. Derp. Many thanks!